# Saving Form Data to Custom Table Magento2

Tags: magento2, forms

I have a form that links to a controller and my goal is to save the data into my custom `vendor_module_table`

```
public function execute()
{
    $post = (array) $this->getRequest()->getPost();

    if (!empty($post)) {
        $customerId = $post['customer_id'];
        $make = $post['make_id'];
        $model = $post['model_id'];
        $year = $post['year_id'];

        # to do - add insert
        $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage('Success!');

        $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
        $resultRedirect->setUrl('/module/controller/add');

        return $resultRedirect;
    }

    $this->_view->loadLayout();
    $this->_view->renderLayout();
}
```

I've come across a few posts online on how to do. My problem with the provided solution is that they all use **object manager** - and this to me feels like a bad practice. Especially when M2 is based on Symfony where I can just call a pre-built save/add function to my controller relating to my form and it just works.. has Magento2 tailored something for this?

E.g. code from my Symfony project:

```
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    # set non-form fields
    $category->setApproved(0);
    $category->setCreatedTs(new \DateTime());

    try {
        # this is how Symfony saves data to a table
        $em->persist($category);
        $em->flush();

        $this->addFlash('success', 'Category Submitted for Review.');
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->addFlash('danger', 'Something went skew-if. Please try again.'. $e->getMessage(). '- ' .$e->getCode());
    }

    return $this->redirectToRoute('category_list');
}
```

**Edit:** Found this in the docs, but it doesn't have a clear example on how to implement - anyone know how to?

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/persistent-entities.html

Comment: Can you add more detail like file path and full code in that file? Thanks

Comment: @AbhishekPanchal which file? :)

Comment: The execute() function is in which file and path?

Comment: @AbhishekPanchal that is the full code ... file is Add.php under `Vendor\Module\Controller\Index`

Comment: You are trying save data via form on Submit?

Comment: @AbhishekPanchal yes :)